# Is is possible to pass operator as variable/parameter in hasura-graphql

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have a requirement where I need two operators(_and and _or) based on the inputs.

So is it possible to pass operator as variable/parameter in hasura graphql?

I am passing "match" variable, the requirement is I should be able to pass "_or" or "_and" based on the some click and also if this is possible then please write down the "Type" of the operator.

```
query Search($match: String) {
  restaurants(where: {_or: [{cuisine: {_ilike: $match}}, {name: {_ilike: $match}}]}) {
    cuisine
    id
    name
    reviews {
      body
    }
  }
}
#variable
{
  "match":"%woodland%"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can construct **the whole where object** depending on your needs;
you can do something like:

```
query($match: restaurants_bool_exp!) {
  restaurants(where: $match) {
    id
    name
    cuisine
    reviews {
      body
    }
  }
}
```

> #variables_1

```
{
  "match": {
    "_or": [
      {
        "name": {
          "_ilike": "%user entered value%"
        }
      },
      {
        "cuisine": {
          "_ilike": "%user entered value%"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> #variables_2

```
{
  "match": {
    "_and": [
      {
        "name": {
          "_ilike": "%user entered value%"
        }
      },
      {
        "cuisine": {
          "_ilike": "%user entered value%"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear, please let me know what you mean by "restaurants_bool_exp" (there is not "type" with this name) and can you format the variables as I am getting  "Variable expected to be "string".

Comment: In graphql, the where argument can accept a "Boolean expression". And "restaurants_bool_exp" is a type used to filter rows from the table `restaurants`. It's mostly "table_name_bool_exp" unless you renamed your table. paste the above query in hasura console and hover on the error so it will show you the right type.